# Transfer Resources to fresh installation

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have live website running on MODx Revolution 2.1.3pl. Some days back I had to restore my entire site from backup. This messed up some file ownerships (for packages installed and images uploaded etc.) because in my server PHP runs as 'nobody' user which is different from my cPanel user.

Now I can't change much things on the server(like installing suPHP because its a shared server) and I don't know which all files are created by PHP, I decided to wipe the site clean and perform a clean install. My site has a large number of already published resources which is impossible to be posted into the new site individually.

Is there any way that I can transfer those resources to the new installation?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a mysql dump of your old site (with [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) or the like) and import this into a new database,  which you use to run your new site from?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it myself but [provisioner](http://modx.com/extras/package/provisioner) seems to do (or at least claim to) what you need.

Comment: provisioner is not what i'm looking for. i'm looking for some tool which can export the resources to files and then import them to the fresh installation (like firefox bookmark manager :) ).
and by the way i tried provisioner and tried connecting to a remote site. It gave an error (access denied).